# Is there a software in which I can make my website's pages layout?

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, web-development, html

I am searching for a software in which I can easily make my website's pages layout by drag n drop type of way.

Is there any?

OS: Windows or Linux

Preference: FOSS/Free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't very clear from your question if you are looking to just make layout i.e. wireframe or you want to create the whole website by drag and drop. Assuming the latter, you could try https://grapesjs.com/

GrapesJS is an open-source, multi-purpose, Web Builder Framework which combines different tools and features with the goal to help you (or users of your application) to build HTML templates without any knowledge of coding. It's a perfect solution to replace the common WYSIWYG editors, which are good for content editing but inappropriate for creating HTML structures.

Comment: Thanks I was struggling with CSS flex box styling to make layout so I thought if I use a template maker kind of software then I can see the code after making it by drag and drop.